# Como puedo resolver este error en Nextjs (Uncaught TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, nextjs

estoy haciendo una app en nextjs al ejecutarla me sale un error en la consola del navegador
[image: error content-script con nextjs]

he buscado una solucion al respecto pero no encuentro una, siento que estoy haciendo mal en mi codigo a pesar que la interaccion con los datos no esta mal hecha, la app funciona bien este error no lo puedo quitar, gracias por cualquier aporte

Comment: en que parte del código te genera ese error? al hacer que? Puedes agregar el código relevante?

Comment: Estas leyendo propiedades de `locale` antes de asignarle un valor. Seguramente funcione bien luego, porque en algún punto le asignas ese valor y listo... pero sin ver código, es pura adivinanza

Comment: en el path `/api/blog/uno` tengo esto: `export async function getServerSideProps(){ const posts = await(await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').json()) return {props: {posts}}` y en el componente tengo: `return <div>{posts.map((post) => { return (<h4 key={post.id}>{post.title}</h4>)  })}</div>`
puedo ver el resultado y todo pero al abrir la consola me sale el error de la imaggen de arriba

Comment: no solo en ese path sino tambien en todos los paths contenidos en `pages/`